# Text align as tabs in <li>

Tags: jquery, html, css

Text align as tabs in < li > that read ***(i) Article*** and so on.

You'll see **Article** that need to align as same on every < li >?

How do I do that in CSS3?

I'm using jQuery 1.8.1 It is for iPhone.

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/align.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/align.png)

**UPDATE:**

Instead of this as below:

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/this.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/this.png)

I see this a it goes off the edge of the page:

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/this2.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/this2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the list-style-type: lower-roman

e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: lower-roman">Article</li>
    <li style="list-style-type: lower-roman">Article</li>
</ul>
```

This will produce:

```
 i. Article
ii. Article
```

However this does not contain the parentheses - not sure how vital these are?

Comment: What about <li style="list-style-type: lower-roman">(ii)  Article 9 Accessibility</li> 

Or is it <li style="list-style-type: lower-roman">Article 9 Accessibility</li>

Comment: I see thanks for the update. I've updated the screen grabs. Its going off the edge of a page.

Comment: It's likely that there is another style conflicting that's making it go off the edge of the page. Tricky to resolve without seeing your full markup and CSS. A work-around might be to wrap your <ul><li /></ul> with a <div style="margin-left: 100px>

Comment: It worked. It is inside <div style="margin-left: 100px><li /></ul></div?

Comment: How come does not contain parentheses?